# heroku:how to get secondary nameserver for ssl https

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-ssl

my hosting platform is freenom which requires two nameservers but heroku gives only on nameserver

is their a way to get secondary nameserver ?

is their a hosting platform which requires only one name server ?

i have tried installing zerigo plugin

```
heroku addons:add zerigo_dns
```

but it says

```
  »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.19.4 to 7.22.8
Creating zerigo_dns on ⬢ dataentrywebsite... !
 !    Couldn't find either the add-on service or the add-on plan of "zerigo_dns".
```

perhaps does not exist anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try poinyDNS which will provide you 3 NS instead of 1 and is quite popular.

Comment: FYI I have configured freenom domain with heroku several times.